# Linear algebra: Finding the number of parameters of a system given dimensions and rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the system Ax = b is consistent and A is a 6 x 7 matrix and rank(A) = 2. How many parameters does the system have?

Comment: The only thing you have to do is to calculate the number of free variables. If $n$ is the number of variables, then $n - r$ is the number of free variables, where $r$ is the rank of the matrix.

Comment: what did you try? show your efforts

Answer (score -1):

Since the rank is the number of non zero rows, there will be 4 zero rows (the number of rows is 6, the rank is 2, another 4 are zero rows). Each zero row represents 1 parameter. Therefore there will be 4 parameters. Consistent means either many solutions or unique solution.

Comment: This is incorrect. And when you talk about zero rows you're referring to the echelon form. But review your basics.